# Moles not working with VS2010 Framework 4 Client Profile

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, c#-4.0, moles, pex

I have build a solution in .net4 Client Profile. Now i have add the test project & tried to add Moles assembly for the my dll.it gives an error saying that

"The Command "path to the Mole.exe" @"path of Mole.args" exited with code - 1008

"Error  210 The command ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Moles\bin\moles.exe" @"D:\Fdi_MainTrack_SCA\FDI UID Renderring\Main_Track\FDI UID Renderer\Fdi.UidRenderer\Fdi.UidRenderer.ObjectManager.Tests\obj\Debug\Moles\moles.args"" exited with code -1008."

can you any one know why this is happening ?

Comment: What does it say in the output tab? (If I remember correctly, moles outputs slightly more useful information to there when it dies)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, no!  The dread 1008 rears up, once again!  There are a couple of things that *may* fix this, and one proven fix:

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio; open the solution and try again
2. Try changing the project type to the full .NET 4.0 profile instead of the client; repeat step 1, if the error persists
3. Re-install the Moles feature set; although inconvenient, this solution fixed my installation.

The trouble is that Moles is an unsupported development project.  It has holes in it, and is subject to failure when other things in your environment change.  Re-installation is sometimes required, to adapt Moles to a change in Visual Studio, or elsewhere on your computer.

I have been using the released version (Fakes isolation Framework), that is a feature set of Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.  I have had no problems at all, with Fakes.  I wish [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/) supported detours, though.

Comment: Thanks for the Comments. I was able to Build the solution , on my PC the one framework dll has been deleted somehow. by replacing that solved my problem. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and got it solved by installing [Visual Studio Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691)